# gpu-manager overwrites xorg.conf

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, gpu, display-manager

I have recently installed the NVIDIA drivers on my Xubuntu 15.10 machine but I had to remove them due to improper multi-monitor setup. Everything went fine, except for the fact that `gpu-manager` seems to overwrite my `xorg.conf` file with a wrong version containing NVIDIA stuff.

I know that there is a [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1310489) related to this, and I tried applying the hotfix suggested there but to no avail; namely, I changed `/etc/init/gpu-manager.conf` to:

```
#start on (starting lightdm
#      or starting gdm
#      or starting kdm
#      or starting xdm
#      or starting lxdm)
task
exec gpu-manager --log /var/log/gpu-manager.log
```

My xorg.config file keeps being overwritten with the NVIDIA stuff.

Any other suggestions? I am also a bit concerned that some people suggested that the hotfix above might freeze the syystem (whatever that means).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, as per [this blogpost](http://nicktj.tumblr.com/post/83943489732/xorgconf-reset-every-boot-in-1404-lts), adding `nogpumanager` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` solves the issue. Thus, the line in `/etc/default/grub` should look like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nogpumanager"
```

After you edit the file, don't forget to run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Tried this, but xorg.conf still gets override

Answer (score 2):

Look here for all possible solution
https://vxlabs.com/2015/02/05/solving-the-ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-346-nvidia-prime-black-screen-issue/#comments

one good solution is

```
 By doing sudo chattr +i /etc/X11/xorg.conf you can prevent any process from changing the file.
```

But then I am not sure `aticonfig --initial` will work

Answer (score 0):

For those who get 640x480 screen or whatever problem and you had touchpad settings in the old overwritten `xorg.conf` file (those settings are already backed up in a file names similar to `xorg.conf.12345678`)
The solution is: after commenting those lines out in  `/etc/init/gpu-manager.conf` like this:

```
#start on (starting lightdm
#      or starting gdm
#      or starting kdm
#      or starting xdm
#      or starting lxdm)
task
exec gpu-manager --log /var/log/gpu-manager.log
```

All you have to do is to remove `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file once then run `sudo service lightdm restart` and after that you see there is a new `xorg.conf` generated.
You can copy old settings from `xorg.conf.12345678` to the end of the new `xorg.conf` file. And restart lightdm service again.