# Overclocking Nvidia on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, cuda

I'm trying to overclock a multi-GPU system running under Ubuntu but somehow it doesn't work.

I have a 10 GPU system based on Nvidia GTX 1060.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Fresh Ubuntu install 16.04
2. Install Nvidia drivers like this:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa 
   sudo apt-get update 
   ubuntu-drivers devices  
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-381
   ```
3. Install CUDA drivers by downloading .deb file from Nvidia (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install cuda
   ```
4. enable overclock with coolbits

   ```
   sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=28 --allow-empty-initial-configuration
   ```

So far, everything is ok, I see that the `xorg.conf` has been updated properly but when I reboot, my `xorg.conf` goes back to a previous version without the overclocking.

I have seen some people experiencing the same issue, some solutions here:
[gpu-manager overwrites xorg.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731990/gpu-manager-overwrites-xorg-conf)
I tried this but ended up with a login loop and being obliged to purge all Nvidia drivers.

When I tried with only one GPU I could overclock the card without any issue but since I added other cards, it doesn't work anymore. The problem seems to come from xorg.conf where my configuration is systematically overwritten.

Any idea of how I could solve this?