# xorg.conf overwritten at boot (gpu-manager disabled)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, xorg.conf

My tweaked xorg.conf file (using nvidia-xconfig) is always overwritten at boot and never loaded. I followed [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731990/gpu-manager-overwrites-xorg-conf) and disabled gpu-manager, but my xorg.conf is still overwritten after that. In gpu-manager.log, there's only one line stating that it's been disabled. What might be the reason the file is overwritten? Where should I go from here?

Answer (score -2):

if you want to prevent a file,you can use follow methods:
1.put a script in /etc/init.d
2.change the permission for the file
Many file system can't be changed permission and will be rewritten after reboot.i recommend you to write a bash script in `/etc/init.d` how for it resetting permission or write the file whenever.