# When I switch to iGPU in my BIOS, I get a black screen instead of logon screen

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

Following the newly acquired knowledge that `prime-select` is only for laptops and in order to switch graphics card for desktops, I have to go to BIOS and switch it there, these are what I did:

1. On the boot sequence, I pressed <kbd>DEL</kbd> key to load the BIOS page.
2. As I have an Asus mother board, I went to **Advanced mode** > **Advanced** >  **System Agent Configuration** > **Graphics Configuration**
3. Then I selected **iGPU** as my Primary Display instead of *Auto* (I didn't touch *Multi Monitor*)

After these steps, I saved and rebooted. Then the boot sequence shows while my HDMI is connected to the integrated graphics card (and it shows nothing if it is connected to the discrete one). Everything seems fine till it gets to the OS' logon screen and it just shows a black one.

What I'm trying to achieve here is to use my Nvidia graphics card for processing only (Cuda) and my integrated one for display. And I'm using a Kubuntu 18.04 with Nvidia driver 430.

BTW, if I disconnect the discrete graphics card completely, everything works (to be honest, I didn't test it with *iGPU* selected, only with *Auto*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the instruction given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061551/how-to-configure-igpu-for-xserver-and-nvidia-gpu-for-cuda-work#), I managed to solve this problem like this:

```
$ lspci  | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e92
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 (rev a1)
```

Take note of `00:02.0`, it will translate to `PCI:0:2:0` (don't ask me how. I don't know).

Now, edit this file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to match this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "intel"
    Driver         "intel"
    BusId          "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "intel"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
EndSection
```

At this point, either reboot the system or run `startx`.

BTW, I don't know why but everything looks much smoother with my integrated graphics card compared to Nvidia!