# fresh 20.04 install with nvidia and iGPU.. only get iGPU resolutions

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I am curious how am I supposed to switch to using the nvidia card on my ubuntu 20.04 setup?

on 18.04 once installed, I could just plug in and go.. seems with 20.04 it is using both iGPU and PCI-E GPU... I see the device is here, I have `nvidia-smi` responding with output.. but the ubuntu gnome resolution is only going up to 1920x1080.. telling me it's using the intel iGPU off my core i7 2600K

Edit:

strangely, after reinstalling.. it now eroneously occupies the GPU even though I only get intel resolutions..

how do I revert so the iGPU is used 100% and the GPU is left freed ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution was given to me and tested via the NVIDIA linux forums

Essentially start the NVIDIA X Server settings:

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-20-04-fresh-install-looking-for-how-to-use-prime-to-use-igpu-on-desktop-intel-gtx-1060/124195/2

under PRIME profiles select

```
NVIDIA OnDemand
```

next, you need to do the following :

- add ‘nogpumanager’ kernel parameter

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters if you're unfamiliar with that step

- delete /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-offload.conf
- create /etc/X11/xorg.conf with contents:

```
   Section "Device"
       Identifier     "intel"
       Driver         "modesetting"
       BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
   EndSection
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I'd just add a note explaining how to get the correct BusID, since it may be different from what you pasted. See my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1099963/803807) for instructions if you'd like to make your answer even more awesome!

Comment: And the first bit is much easier to do with just `sudo prime-select on-demand`

Comment: Please note that this renders nvidia-settings unusable

Comment: the step to create xorg.conf was what allowed me to switch between intel and nvidia on my Lenovo Legion 5pi. Prior to this I could only get intel to work and logging in the GDM when using nvidia just caused Ubuntu to hang.

on-demand does not work for me. Even without specifying the environment variables, everything uses nvidia.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the driver in Software & Updates --> Additional Drivers.

Comment: This doesn't work. Nvidia drivers still take over when you do this. This answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1243949/803807 solves the issue.