# Ubuntu 20.04 use Intel for graphics and NVIDIA GPU for CUDA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, cuda

I am trying to configure Ubuntu 20.04 to use the integrated Intel graphics for xorg and leave the NVIDIA GPU as free as possible to CUDA programs. Such that `nvidia-smi` shows no process using the GPU.

I am following the answer in

[fresh 20.04 install with nvidia and iGPU.. only get iGPU resolutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229974/fresh-20-04-install-with-nvidia-and-igpu-only-get-igpu-resolutions/1243949#1243949)

(and links therein)

At one point it is recommended to delete the file:

`xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-offload.conf`

which on my Ubuntu 20.04 system is not present. I see only:

```
> $:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ ll
> total 36 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096
> May  2 11:06 ./ drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May  2 10:10 ../
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 Oct 22  2019 10-amdgpu.conf
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  206 Mar 19 07:58 10-nvidia.conf
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1350 Apr  8 08:29 10-quirks.conf
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 Oct 22  2019 10-radeon.conf
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  333 May  4 11:23 11-nvidia-prime.conf
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1429 Aug 13  2019 40-libinput.conf
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3458 Mar 11  2020 70-wacom.conf
```

Should I delete `11-nvidia-prime.conf` ?

What I've done so far:

1. sudo prime-select on-demand
2. created /etc/X11/xorg.conf
3. Upon reboot will add the kernel parameter 'nogpumanagaer'

Answer (score 1):

I took the risk and rebooted (with the added kernel parameter).
It worked, no need to delete `11-nvidia-prime.conf`.