# Use integrated GPU for desktop display and leave dedicated GPU for computing tasks on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, xorg, 22.04, intel-graphics, dual-graphics

I have just built a desktop for Deep Learning, using Ubuntu 22.04.

My purpose is straightforward - use IGPU (i7 13700K) for display purposes and leave DGPU (RTX 3090) free for Deep Learning tasks.

In the past, I had done this successfully on my Laptop Lenovo Y520 (i7 7700HQ, GTX 1050) by following [method 1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1099963), but with Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried the old method, but it did not work (when I plugged HDMI into Mainboard, it showed a black screen). So, I moved to [method 2](https://askubuntu.com/a/1243949/803807) (with some additional steps, which are proven to work on Ubuntu 20.04). However, the result showed no differences.

Did someone manage to perform this on Ubuntu 22.04 successfully, could you share your experience?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried method 2 on ubuntu 22, it works.
My computer is DELL R720xd and I only have one tesla p4 on my computer