# Cannot run nvidia-settings after setting "coolbits" as unusable xorg.conf is created

Tags: nvidia, xorg.conf

I have iGpu (i7-6700) and three NVidia mining cards, all P102-100.  These cards do not have display out.  I am using them under Boinc for to process WCG-covid and Einstein GPU work units.  They are similar to GTX 1080TI except for the video out.

If I run  "nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=4" I suspect the cool bits are set.  Unfortunately, nvidia-config rewrites (creats) xorg.conf and after a rebooting I have lost my display.  I can ssh in with putty but can no longer use VNC or the actual monitor/keyboard.  The xorg.conf is setup as if the graphic coprocessor have a video output which they do not.  Since there is no longer any display, nvidia-settings cannot run.  I would like to set the clock speed down as the boards run too hot.  If I delete the xorg.conf file and reboot then the display comes back up just fine even though the xorg.conf file no longer exists.

Can I add something to that NVidia xorg.conf file to make it use the iGpu?  This is Ubuntu 18.04 and NVidia driver 470.  How is it that if I delete the xorg.conf the display works using the iGpu?

```
jstateson@h110btc:~$ lspci | grep VGA
```

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
jstateson@h110btc:~$

Answer (score 0):

Read this
[How to configure iGPU for xserver and nvidia GPU for CUDA work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061551/how-to-configure-igpu-for-xserver-and-nvidia-gpu-for-cuda-work)

thanks to "Ian&Steve C" over at einsteinathome

I had to add the following also

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen         "intel"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" Rightof "intel"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection
```