# Kubuntu after update black screen with cursor (but startx brings me a desktop)

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, xorg

After the latest update of kubuntu I end up with a black screen and a cursor. But if i switch to a new terminal and execute `startx` I get a desktop as usual. Well with some minor problems like to connect to the wlan I have to re-enter my password. and firefox only starts in safe mode. I have an nvidia (hybrid) card in my notebook which causes problems every now and then. But I need this card for cuda only anyways so I want my x session to use the intel only driver.

```
kic@kic:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ ll
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jan 11 15:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K Jan 11 15:40 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  327 Okt 20 18:10 10-intel-only.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.4K Dez 18 14:08 10-quirks.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 Okt 22  2019 10-radeon.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  341 Okt 20 20:15 11-nvidia-prime.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.5K Mai 30  2020 40-libinput.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.4K Mär 11  2020 70-wacom.conf
```

The 11-nvidia-prime.conf is empty (everything is commented)
and the 10-intel-only.conf looks like so:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "Layout0"
    Option "AutoAddGPU" "false"
    Screen 0 "IntelScreen"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "IntelDevice"
    BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
    Driver "intel" # or maybe "modesetting"?
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "IntelScreen"
    Device "IntelDevice"
EndSection
```

everything as I have stated in this old question: [Use NVIDIA Hybrid gpu only for CUDA and not for KDE Plasma](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282076/use-nvidia-hybrid-gpu-only-for-cuda-and-not-for-kde-plasma/1285543#1285543)

EDIT 1:
looks like something happens to the Auth module in the sddm-helper:

```
● sddm.service - Simple Desktop Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-01-11 15:42:52 CET; 14min ago
       Docs: man:sddm(1)
             man:sddm.conf(5)
    Process: 1168 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/bin/sddm" ] (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1171 (sddm)
      Tasks: 13 (limit: 37766)
     Memory: 107.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/sddm.service
             ├─1171 /usr/bin/sddm
             └─1174 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{612186ef-7698-4c41-bee6-68ce4ac7e66a} -background none -noreset -displayfd 17 -seat seat0 vt1

Jan 11 15:42:55 kic sddm[1171]: Greeter starting...
Jan 11 15:42:55 kic sddm[1171]: Adding cookie to "/var/run/sddm/{612186ef-7698-4c41-bee6-68ce4ac7e66a}"
Jan 11 15:42:55 kic sddm-helper[1289]: [PAM] Starting...
Jan 11 15:42:55 kic sddm-helper[1289]: [PAM] Authenticating...
Jan 11 15:42:55 kic sddm-helper[1289]: [PAM] returning.
Jan 11 15:42:55 kic sddm-helper[1289]: pam_unix(sddm-greeter:session): session opened for user sddm by (uid=0)
Jan 11 15:42:55 kic sddm[1171]: Greeter session started successfully
Jan 11 15:42:56 kic sddm[1171]: Message received from greeter: Connect
Jan 11 15:43:02 kic sddm[1171]: Auth: sddm-helper exited with 11
Jan 11 15:43:02 kic sddm[1171]:
```

EDIT 2: add syslog

```
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm[10814]: Running display setup script  "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup"
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm[10814]: Display server started.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm[10814]: Socket server starting...
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm[10814]: Socket server started.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm[10814]: Loading theme configuration from "/usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze/theme.conf"
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm[10814]: Greeter starting...
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm[10814]: Adding cookie to "/var/run/sddm/{9db02c8f-8b53-4b9d-92a9-af3eb0bd6fc9}"
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm-helper[10836]: [PAM] Starting...
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm-helper[10836]: [PAM] Authenticating...
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm-helper[10836]: [PAM] returning.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 120.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/120...
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[1]: Finished User Runtime Directory /run/user/120.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 120...
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Reached target Paths.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Reached target Timers.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Listening on debconf communication socket.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Listening on Sound System.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Reached target Sockets.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Reached target Basic System.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 120.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Starting Sound Service...
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[1]: Started Session 15 of user sddm.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm[10814]: Greeter session started successfully
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm-greeter[10850]: High-DPI autoscaling not Enabled
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm-greeter[10850]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop"
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm-greeter[10850]: Loading theme configuration from "/usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze/theme.conf"
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic systemd[10840]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic dbus-daemon[10853]: [session uid=120 pid=10853] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm-greeter[10850]: Connected to the daemon.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm[10814]: Message received from greeter: Connect
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic rtkit-daemon[1303]: Successfully made thread 10849 of process 10849 owned by '120' high priority at nice level -11.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic rtkit-daemon[1303]: Supervising 7 threads of 7 processes of 2 users.
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm-greeter[10850]: Loading file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze/Main.qml...
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm-greeter[10850]: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.#012(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7ffd666f1f40), parent's thread is QThread(0x55b1ee8a85a0), current thread is QThread(0x55b1ee937070)
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm-greeter[10850]: message repeated 2 times: [ QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.#012(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7ffd666f1f40), parent's thread is QThread(0x55b1ee8a85a0), current thread is QThread(0x55b1ee937070)]
Jan 11 18:01:56 kic sddm-greeter[10850]: QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
Jan 11 18:01:57 kic sddm-greeter[10850]: Adding view for "eDP1" QRect(0,0 3840x2160)
Jan 11 18:01:57 kic rtkit-daemon[1303]: Supervising 7 threads of 7 processes of 2 users.
Jan 11 18:01:57 kic rtkit-daemon[1303]: Successfully made thread 10866 of process 10849 owned by '120' RT at priority 5.
Jan 11 18:01:57 kic rtkit-daemon[1303]: Supervising 8 threads of 7 processes of 2 users.
Jan 11 18:01:57 kic rtkit-daemon[1303]: Supervising 8 threads of 7 processes of 2 users.
Jan 11 18:01:57 kic rtkit-daemon[1303]: Successfully made thread 10867 of process 10849 owned by '120' RT at priority 5.
Jan 11 18:01:57 kic rtkit-daemon[1303]: Supervising 9 threads of 7 processes of 2 users.
Jan 11 18:01:57 kic systemd[10840]: Started Sound Service.
Jan 11 18:01:57 kic systemd[10840]: Reached target Main User Target.
Jan 11 18:01:57 kic systemd[10840]: Startup finished in 1.207s.
Jan 11 18:02:00 kic kernel: [ 8357.923576] QSGRenderThread[10865]: segfault at 24 ip 00007fcb574e8c34 sp 00007fcb3b7fcd20 error 6 in iris_dri.so[7fcb569a5000+e54000]
Jan 11 18:02:00 kic kernel: [ 8357.923582] Code: 2b 7e 28 01 c7 81 ff db ff 00 00 0f 87 f5 18 00 00 48 01 c8 48 89 46 30 48 85 c9 0f 84 c0 05 00 00 83 ea 01 81 ca 00 00 09 78 <89> 11 48 8d 51 04 45 85 ff 74 76 41 8d 47 ff 48 8d 4c c1 0c 0f 1f
Jan 11 18:02:01 kic sddm-helper[10836]: [PAM] Closing session
Jan 11 18:02:01 kic sddm-helper[10836]: [PAM] Ended.
Jan 11 18:02:01 kic sddm[10814]: Auth: sddm-helper exited with 11
```

Comment: i have purged sddm and use now ly, the desktop starts as usual but al lot of stuff is still crashing like VLC or even Discover. I guess something destroyed Plasma?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. I am using lubuntu which comes by default with sddm display manager. It all worked fine. After the last upgrade and after a reboot, sddm refuses to start and displays a mouse icon over a black screen instead....

I tried to purge sddm and reinstall it => same !

I solved it temporarily by setting Auto Login, eg:
sudo vi /etc/sddm.conf
Add line User=my_user_name

=> done !